# Remove URL parts and rewrite it with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

My website has urls like http://domain.com/index.php?page=events/eventdetails/1/Silver+Jubilee, http://domain.com/index.php?page=events/announcementdetails/2, http://domain.com/index.php?page=events/announcementdetails/3 etc which I want to change to http://domain.com/Events/Eventdetails/1/Silver+Jubilee, http://domain.com/Announcements/Announcementdetails/3 .

Currently my htaccess file is as shown below in which I am doing URL rewriting for some other pages.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule  AboutUs$ /index.php?page=home/aboutus [QSA,L]
RewriteRule  Announcements$ /index.php?page=events/announcements [QSA,L]
RewriteRule  Church-Officials$ /index.php?page=account/official [QSA,L]
RewriteRule  PhotoGallery$ /index.php?page=gallery/album [QSA,L]
RewriteRule  VideoGallery$ /index.php?page=videogallery/videos [QSA,L]
RewriteRule  ContactUs$ /index.php?page=home/contactus [QSA,L]
RewriteRule  Vicar-Message$ /index.php?page=events/allmessages [QSA,L]
RewriteRule  Events$ /index.php?page=events/event [QSA,L]
RewriteRule  Gallery-Images$ /index.php?page=gallery/photos [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

How it can be done using htaccess? Can anyone help me to do it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `.htaccess` in your web root `/` directory

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\ /index\.php\?page=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://domain.com/%1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^[A-Z]{3,}\ /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: What's the browser URL you used? You need to lowercase your directory names (in the URL) if `index.php`'s `page` parameter is case-sensitive.